# Create users from client on Realm Mobile Platform

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is there anyway to create/register user with new product Realm Mobile Platform from [realm.io](http://realm.io)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code example is in the official docs, but I haven't tested it:

```
let usernameCredential = Credential.usernamePassword(username: "username", password: "password", actions: [.createAccount])
```

the `actions: [.createAccount]` indicates that yes, you can create a user from an app, if that is what you meant.

Comment: Working fine, but is there anyway to send verification email or other advanced register process? Maybe on enterprise version?

Comment: Probably on the enterprise version

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will register for test enterprise version

Comment: @mhergon - If you can't send an email.  How about presenting a user notification?